# How to safely let users to enter custom math functions for a graphing program

Tags: python, eval, user-input

I'm developing a graphing program in Python that let's the user type in the formula for a math function (something like `f(x) = 2*x*sin(x)`) and then plot it in an animated way. Currently I've implemented this using `eval()`, but I'm aware of how dangerous it is and how tricky it is to prevent it from executing malicious code---if it's even possible.

Browsing the StackOverflow archives, I found `ast.literal_eval()` as a possible solution, but it would restrict formulas from containing named functions like `sin`, `log`, and other custom functions that I've defined. Moreover, I'd like to allow users to enter more sophisticated formulas using standard Python syntax like

`f(x) = x**2 if x<0 else x`

`f(x) = sum([1/n**x for n in range(1,11)])`

so that piecewise and sum formulas can be graphed.

A possible solution I thought of: If I could somehow disallow my Python program from writing to the disk, accessing the internet, or executing external programs, then this would (as best I can tell) prevent any permanently damaging code from being run (e.g. wiping the disk, transmitting private information, etc.).

Is there a way to internally to disable a Python program from writing to disk, accessing the internet, or executing external programs? Or, failing that, is there any other way I can safely allow the user to enter custom math functions while also preserving as much freedom for them to use more complex expressions?

Comment: What about a whitelist?

Comment: @infinitezero: How do you mean?

Comment: He means a list of the allowed words, for example `whitelist = ["sin", "cos", "tan"]`. And then you check that all the words in the command are in your whitelist

Comment: @infinitezero A whitelist alone is not enough. In fact, [there's always a way to access the builtins even if everything is blocked](https://gist.github.com/Aran-Fey/2667cef9420e930e57d80187a76e35e4).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Perhaps I'm missing something, but in your example, the final `eval()` statement contains "words" like `__builtins__`, `__class__`, etc. True, no builtins are explicitly written, but wouldn't these special double-underscore words get blocked by a whitelist that only included such words as `if`, `else`, `cos`, `sum`, etc.?

Comment: @WB-man There's nothing preventing me from renaming the `__builtins__` variable to something like `sum`. The point is that I can gain access to everything I want from a simple string literal. Or any other literal. Trying to make `eval` or `exec` safe is an endeavor that's pretty much guaranteed to fail. The best way to make sure nobody can do anything evil is to write your own `eval`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I agree that you could simply rename `__builtins__` as `sum` *before* calling `eval`, but how could you do that from *within* an `eval` expression? In my own program, the only way an attacker could rename a variable (or otherwise run any code) is via an `eval` expression which would be filtered thru the whitelist before being run.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Let's leave the variable name thing aside: The expression `''.__class__.__class__.__subclasses__(type)[0].register.__globals__['__loader__'].get_data.__globals__['sys'].modules['builtins']` lets me access the builtins. I don't even have to assign that to a variable if I don't want to, I can just use that expression to access the builtins. How exactly would your filter catch that?

Comment: Suppose my whitelist consists of only a few names like `["sin", "cos", "tan"]` so that my users have access to those functions. Before evaluating your expression, I would first parse it to extract all isolated alphanumeric (including underscore) substrings and then check that each one is in the whitelist. If any are not, an error is raised and the expression is not evaluated. In the case of your expression the names `__class_`, `get_data`, etc. would all be extracted and found to not be in the whitelist.

Comment: I suppose that would work. You just have to find a way to let the user use variables in their formulas (like the `x` in `x**2 if x<0 else x`) without accidentally giving attackers too much freedom. Maybe only allow variables with a length of 1 or something like that.

Comment: That's more or less what I was planning to do. The independent variable name for the function is fixed to be `x` from the start, and the only variable names allowed for expressions like `sum([1/n**x for n in range(1,11)])` are single characters (`n` in this case).